# Creating Columns in m x 1 dataframe based on spaces in each row?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an m x 1 dataframe where each row's information is collapsed in one column, separated by spaces. I was wondering how to get each data point into its own column. For example I would like this (1x1) row:

```
 0.159 6.226681E-3 4.902898E+1 2.45
```

to turn into this (1x4):

```
column1    column 2         column 3        column 4
0.159      6.226681E-3      4.902898E+1      2.45
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve your problem?

Comment: yes I have tried using str.split but maybe not doing it correctly. Also tried using the answer suggested by scnerd but had no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following?

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(df['my_funky_column'].apply(str.split)), columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])
```

Comment: This creates an empty matrix with the 4 columns

Comment: @MattM See my edited answer. Needed to convert the result of ``apply`` into a list.

Comment: @MattM Glad that helped you, please accept the answer if it solves your question